# How to insert Hindi Fonts in Mysql using Codeigniter Framework

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, unicode

I want to Insert Hindi fonts to Mysql database table using PHP CodeIgniter Framework.

I have altered table columns to **`CHARSET utf8`** and also collation to **`utf8_general_ci`**. But still Hindi fonts are inserting as garbage characters.

I also tried to describe **`mysql_set_charset('utf8');`**  before insert Query but the result is the same.

Comment: What are the 'garbage' characters exactly? Have you remembered to include `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` (or the `Content-Type` header with the same charset parameter)?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested add this meta tag in the header of views (HTML) markups header.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

And as your question states change the **collation** of your field to **utf8_general_ci**.
This solved my problem totally.

Hope it will yours too.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with accented characters and I had tried the same thing you did. But additionally I had also used this function

```
htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

Pass your data through above function before inserting it in DB.

Also while showing the same data to the user, pass it via

```
html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

It worked for me, and I hope it works for you too :)

Comment: did you use any specific php excel library ? I need to import hindi, english, math calculus formula, graphs and even images into mysql